# JQuery enter event doesn't trigger form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, input, triggers, submit

Usually, when we press enter on an input inside a form with a submit button it triggers its form submission, but when i tried to get the same result by calling JQuery's trigger function it doesn't work. any idea why?

```
var ev =$.Event('keydown',{keyCode:13});
$('#myInput').trigger(ev);
```

The event is called but the form doesn't submit.

Comment: `MyFormName.submit()`

Comment: You might want to just call click `$('#myInput').trigger("click");` or submit() like the others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').on('change',function(){

document.getElementsByName('formName').submit();
});
```

Comment: This would be a better quality answer if it included a plain-English explanation, and answered OP's original question of "Why (his code doesn't work)".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know I can call the form by id, but what I don't understand is why pressing enter works and triggering it doesn't.